# MySQL Error Code 1072- Can't create a Foreign Key

Tags: mysql

I created this table:

```
    create table users 
(
    id_user int not null auto_increment,
    username varchar (255) not null,
    email varchar (255) not null,
    CONSTRAINT id_user PRIMARY KEY (id_user)
);
```

And now I am trying to create this one:

```
create table games
(
    id_game int not null auto_increment,
    game_name varchar (255) not null,
    preco decimal (6,2),
    autor varchar (255) not null,
    CONSTRAINT id_game PRIMARY KEY (id_game),
    CONSTRAINT autor FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES users (username)
);
```

The idea is to make the column username from the table users a foreign key in the table games as "autor". However, I am getting this error:

> Error 1072. Key Column "username" doesn't exist in table.

Comment: The error itself explains the error. In the `games` table you're trying to make the "id_user" as its primary key, but that column doesn't exist in that (`games`) table

Comment: Looks like a simple copy & paste mistake.

Comment: Yeah, I did not notice I was using "id_user" as PK. However, the same error happens with the "autor" column, the Foreign Key. It goes like "username" doesnt exist in the table, despite the fact I referenced it in the late lines...

Comment: "the same error happens with the "autor" column" - what does that mean? There's no column named  `username` in the `games`  table